# Steps not defined in FeatureContext file. I have the steps defined. Not sure if the featurecontext file is being invoked

Tags: drupal, behat, mink

This is my behat.yml file. I tried variants inorder to link the FeatureContext file. Can someone help me by checking if that is the right way to link the feature context file in the behat.yml file. in case path for the featurecontext file is required this is the path `%path.base%/features/bootstrap`

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      path: %paths.base%/features
      contexts: 
             - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
             - FeatureContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://echidnaacerdev.prod.acquia-sites.com/
      sessions:
        default:
          goutte: ~
```

This is my FeatureContext.php file

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext implements Context
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
    * Click some text
    *
    * @When /^I click on the text :text$/
    */
    public function iClickOnTheText($text)
    {
        $session = $this->getSession();
        $element = $session->getPage()->find('xpath',$session->getSelectorsHandler()->selectorToXpath('xpath', '*//*[text()="'. $text .'"]'));
        if (null === $element) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Cannot find text: "%s"', $text));
        }

        $element->click();

    }
}
```

Im not sure how to i define the feature context file in my behat.yml. Can anyone help me out with this. the error message i get is that the 

`behat\minkextension\context\minkcontext has missing steps. define them with the snippets`

For the particular step `When I click on the text "Members"`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the step correctly, you should use `When I click on the text Members` , remember the matching is done by regular expression and the sintax should be Gherkin or Turnip.

`FeatureContext` should extend `MinkContext`
Remove `MinkContext` from yml, is not needed if you extend it as I said, also you can remove that path, by default it is looking in `features/bootstrap`